# Delphi: TIdUDPServer как настроить

Tags: delphi, udp

`TIdUDPServer` используется следующим способом:

```
procedure TMainAppForm.FormCreate;
begin
    IdUDPServer1.Bindings.add.IP    := '127.0.0.1'; // как вариант адрес компьютера 
    IdUDPServer1.Bindings.add.Port  := 49152;
    IdUDPServer1.Active             := True;
    IdUDPServer1.OnUDPRead          := IdUDPServer1UDPRead;
end;

procedure TMainAppForm.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
                                       const AData: TIdBytes;
                                       ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
    MessageBox(...);
end;
```

Почему-то не вызывается `IdUDPServer1UDPRead`, когда приходят `UDP` пакеты на данный порт.

Comment: Метод Add надо вызывать только один раз для пары ip/порт: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10590271

Comment: И событие OnUDPRead надо назначать ДО того, как вы начинаете слушать порт, а не после.

Comment: Переделал, все равно не заработало.

Comment: Строку IdUDPServer1.OnUDPRead поднять чуточку выше (перед активацией). После старта сторонними средствами посмотреть, действительно ли слушается UDP порт (CurrPorts от NirSoft).